# indexing web urls content using nutch inject

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, nutch

I had crawled recursively a website and collected all the links/sublinks ie url mentioned in it.Now I wanted it to dump all the html contents to the elasticsearch.

I was going through nutch [tutorial](https://qbox.io/blog/scraping-the-web-with-nutch-for-elasticsearch) and found below way to do so:

```
 2. Inject the URLs into the Crawldb

      nutch inject seed/urls.txt


3. Generate URLs to fetch

    bin/nutch generate -topN 40

4. Fetch the pages

   bin/nutch fetch -all
```

while doing it,I am getting below error:

```
$ ./nutch inject seed/urls.txt
   Usage: Injector <crawldb> <url_dir> [-overwrite] [-update]
```

Here,In urls.txt I had put all the web links seperated by new line.
I am not sure how to extract all data and push to ES using nutch and unable to find any reference links to do,need pointers on this.

Comment: checking the output of the inject command you need to specify the `crawldb` path which usually is `crawl/crawldb` but really depends on the name that you chose.

Answer (score 0):

The command inject needs two arguments. The first one is `crawldb`, which is the location where Nutch stores its data during the crawling. What you use normally is `crawl/crawldb`, but you can choose a different name as well as @Jorge Luis pointed out in his comment. The second one is `url_dir`, which is the location of the *directory* where the text file containing start URLs is located. In your case this would be `seed`.

So the complete command for you to run is

```
./nutch inject crawl/crawldb seed
```